# Add php text string to the code

Tags: php, string, text

I have so stupid issue which I just can't resolve now and I need it so much..

So here's the code:

```
 $siteURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';

$bookmarklet = 'javascript:document.location.href=\'' . $siteURL . '?url=\'+escape(document.location.href)';
```

it takes things from url, like "domain.com/?url=things"

I need the code to add http:// before "things"

I've tried adding `$bookmarklet = 'http://'. $bookmarklete` and changing it in various ways but it didn't helped.

Please help me guys!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand but, something as simple as `'url=http://'+escape(...`?

Comment: You have to use php function to scape the url from php side.

Comment: You also have an error in your code. The last ` right after `href)`.

Comment: document.location.href already includes the http:// so you shouldn't need to add it...

Comment: I have code to run java applet. But for java applet need http://. I can't paste http:// to link (which would be better) because of the 403.. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/0PBDcBTV.

Comment: this is full page code: http://pastebin.com/tmeEQMzY

Comment: $bookmarklet doesn't seem to be used in the script you have shared. Are you grabbing "domain.com/?url=things" from the current page url?

Comment: Yes this is also rare for me, but however it seems to be taking bookmarklet. I guess it takes only the "things". This is not mine script

Comment: Christian it's strange, but it's not error. The script without it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like line 72 of your full code is using the query string url from the page url going to the variable $url

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

try changing to:

```
$url = 'http://'.$_GET['url'];
```

Are you trying to change this bit of the code? You question is not very clear on what needs to be changed (what is it now Vs what you want it to be) or where your example url is coming from and where in your $bookmarklet string the 'url' part needs to go... if anywhere?

Your actual $bookmarklet string looks ok to me although as I said before it is not used in the script so you can assign it anything you like and I can't imagine it making any difference!

You could tidy the $bookmark string to this:

```
$bookmarklet = "javascript:location.href='$siteURL?url='+encodeURI(location.href)";
```

`encodeURI()` is the newer replacement for `escape()`